# Skype for Business on Mac no main menu

Tags: mac, skype-for-business

I am essentially trying to change the font and font size for chat in Skype for Business on a Mac.

As of now I don't have a main menu screen so there is no option or tool tab to get to where you normally would on a PC/Windows.

Attached is a screen shot of what my "main menu" looks like.

Also there is nothing at the top in the tool bar that allows me to change the font type or size.

[image: Skype Main Menu]

Comment: This is horrible, tiny font on an external monitor!

Answer (score 1):

Keep noted that Skype for Business on a MAC is often limited as the first client which gets new features is the Skype for Business client on Windows.

So on the MAC you have only limited options:

[image]

[image]

And changing the Fontsize is currently not part from that client.